# How to overide ui component form in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, overrides, uicomponent, adminform, cms-pages

I want to add a custom field in cms page form in admin side. 
cms_page_form is created by using ui component form. How can I override this form in my custom module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create **Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_page_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="identifier_test">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Test Input</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">identifier_test</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```